# Does $n+1=x^{\varphi(n)}$ have a solution for every $n$?

Tags: number-theory

Euler's theorem states that if $n$ and $a$ are coprime positive integers, then

$a^{\varphi(n)}\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$.
 Where $\phi(n)$ is Euler's totient function.

Fix $n$. Is the equation $n+1=x^{\varphi(n)}$ has a solution for every $n$?

Comment: This is very unlikely. Even for $x=2$, $2^{\varphi(n)}$ is much larger than $n+1$ for sufficiently large $n$

Comment: For small $n$, we have some solutions: $n=2$, $x=3$, and $n=3$, $x=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this were true, then $n+1$ would always be a perfect power when $n>2$, since then $\phi(n)>1$. In particular, if $n+1$ is prime (or square-free,) then $x^{\phi(n)}=n+1$ is only possible if $\phi(n)=1$, or $n=1,2$.

You can actually show that it is rarely possible, because for all but finitely many $n$, $\phi(n)>\log_2 (n+1)$ and thus $x^{\phi(n)}>n+1$.